# Как обновить store next.js redux-wrapper?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Привет!
Использую next.js с redux и axios. redux в качестве npm next-redux-wrapper. Axios для получения данных по url api. Есть вопрос, почему не получается принять новый state?
На картинке видно, что action получил свое значение, а next state остается пустым, в чем может быть проблема?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, типы action в reducer не совпадали.вот так